# How to convert Dictionary<string, object> to List<T>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, generics

I have a `User` class

```
public class  User
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Email { get; set; }    
}
```

and a `Dictionary`

```
public Dictionary<string, object> models = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"Users[0].Id", 1},
    {"Users[0].Name", "Rajib"},
    {"Users[0].Email", "rajib@azr.com"},
    {"Users[1].Id", 2},
    {"Users[1].Name", "Ashiq"},
    {"Users[1].Email", "azhiq@azr.com"},
    {"Users[2].Id", 3},
    {"Users[2].Name", "Zaman"},
    {"Users[2].Email", "zaman@azr.com"},
};
```

Now I want to convert the value of `Dictionary<string, object> models` to `List<User>`.
Can anyone suggest me how to do that?

Comment: `"Users[0].Id"`. Is that actually a string value in `Dictionary`?

Comment: Yes. this is actually string value @NikhilAgrawal

Comment: Your usage of strings for C# code snippets/expressions (such as "Users[0].Id" for example) in your scenario is very strange. Do you really have to use such a dictionary in the first place?

Comment: basically this came from ASP.NET MVC RAZOR view engine. I develop a very complex dynamic HTML FORM Using RAZOR.Aad i pass a list of elements via jQuey AJAX as a Dictonary.     @elgonzo

Comment: Are you trying to get a collection of `User` in a POST method?

Comment: this is insane. You can't possibly be in a situation where you have to deal with this.  If you are using some software that actually forces you to deal with this then you should stop using that software.  But what is probably happening is that you have completely misunderstood what is going on.

Comment: Yes. You are right.@StephenMuecke

Comment: And there is no such thing an 'passing a list of elements via ajax as a Dictionary!

Comment: The just make the parameter in your POST method `IEnumerable<User>` and it will be bound correctly.

Comment: you would use dictionary when you want to access items by some property without searching entire database. for example in your case if you want to query Users by name you would use dictionary with UserName as key and User as item. `Dictionary<string, User>` and you can find users by their name using this dictionary.

Comment: @StephenMuecke this is an example. There are no properties in the class except ID. all properties are being generated at run time. after submitting the form i  convert all data as a dictionary like my example. now i want to convert to list

Comment: Sorry, You not making any sense.

Comment: may be, but that's exactly what i need.:(

Comment: I very much doubt that. You say you're "converting all data as a dictionary like my example" - that suggests you could do something else instead, such as converting it to JSON if you need a string representation...

Comment: @Ashiquzzaman "this is an example. There are no properties in the class except ID" -- In your question, you give `Name` and `Email` as properties of the class. If they're not, your question is utterly useless, as answers you receive here that do assume they're properties aren't going to be of any help to you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is strange what you wanna do and I think you should rethink your design. Maybe you can do something differently with how you construct your data...
But this is how you can achieve it:

Group your data by the first part of the `key`, indicating a different `User` then project for each group a different `User` object. You can use reflection to assign the `value` to each correct property

```
var data = models.GroupBy(item => item.Key.Substring(0, item.Key.IndexOf(".")))
      .Select(group => group.Aggregate(new User(), (user, item) =>
      {
          PropertyInfo propertyInfo = user.GetType().GetProperty(item.Key.Substring(item.Key.IndexOf(".") + 1));
          propertyInfo.SetValue(user, Convert.ChangeType(item.Value, propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
          return user;
      })).ToList();
```

Comment: I will keep your suggestion in mind. Actually your answer solved my problem successfully. Thank's.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work for you.

```
var list = new List<User>();
for(var i = 0; i < models.Count/3; i++)
{
    var user = new User();
    user.Id = (int)models[string.Format("Users[{0}].Id", i)];
    user.Name = models[string.Format("Users[{0}].Name", i)].ToString();
    user.Email = models[string.Format("Users[{0}].Email", i)].ToString();
    list.Add(user);
}
```

But it is really strange to have this kind of `Dictionary`